# R print graphic within if

Tags: r, pdf, rstudio

I got a serious problem with R. I got the following example code in RStudio. First getting a map of Berlin and print it if the oneMap variable is true. 
As oneMap is set to true the code should print me the Berlin map and print "test" to the terminal. If I execute the code there is no map printed but the "test" is printed to the console.
Why is the map not printed? Thanks for your help!

```
library(ggmap)

oneMap = TRUE

berlin = qmap("Berlin", zoom=13, color="bw", legend = "topleft")

if(oneMap){
  #print map
  berlin    
  cat("test")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose the `berlin` object in a `print()` function. This is true whenever you want to print graphs inside of functions, for loops, and conditional blocks.